# Javascript API: Function outside of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a getting the following error: SyncNavigationSetCssToState is not defined

```
$(function () {
    var NavigationSetApi = {
        SyncNavigationSetCssToState: function (navigationSet) {
            var navigationSetContent = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-content");
            var navigationSetHeaderButton = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-header-button");

            if (navigationSetContent.is(":visible"))
                navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
            else
                navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        },

        GetAllNavigationSets: function () {
            return $(".navigation-set");
        },

        SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState: function () {
            this.GetAllNavigationSets().each(function () {
                SyncNavigationSetCssToState($(this));
            });
        }
    }

    NavigationSetApi.SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState();
}
```

I can't work out how I can get access to SyncNavigationSetCssToState from within the each() function within SyncNavigationSetCssToState. How can I reference the main api object from here please?

Comment: Use `this` and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing `this` when calling `SyncNavigationSetCssToState`

Replace your call with `NavigationSetApi.SyncNavigationSetCssToState`

```
$(function () {
    var NavigationSetApi = {
        SyncNavigationSetCssToState: function (navigationSet) {
            var navigationSetContent = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-content");
            var navigationSetHeaderButton = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-header-button");

            if (navigationSetContent.is(":visible"))
                navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
            else
                navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        },

        GetAllNavigationSets: function () {
            return $(".navigation-set");
        },

        SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState: function () {
            this.GetAllNavigationSets().each(function () {
                NavigationSetApi.SyncNavigationSetCssToState($(this));
            });
        }
    }

    NavigationSetApi.SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState();
}
```

---

Expanding on comment about instance...

Above is just a simple Javascript object. `this` refers to the object `NavigationSetApi` to keep it simple. But when you call `this.GetAllNavigationSets().each`, `each` is now setting `this` by using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

If you were to use `NavigationSetApi` as an instance you would first need to make it a function (If you know any OO languages think of a class)

This is how you would define it:

```
function NavigationSetApi(){

}

NavigationSetApi.prototype = {
    SyncNavigationSetCssToState: function (navigationSet) {
        var navigationSetContent = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-content");
        var navigationSetHeaderButton = navigationSet.find(".navigation-set-header-button");

        if (navigationSetContent.is(":visible"))
            navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
        else
            navigationSetHeaderButton.removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    },

    GetAllNavigationSets: function () {
        return $(".navigation-set");
    },

    SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState: function () {
        //From Blake Simpson's answer
        var api = this;
        this.GetAllNavigationSets().each(function () {
            api.SyncNavigationSetCssToState($(this));
        });
    }
};
```

And then to call it you would use

```
var instanceApi = new NavigationSetApi();
instanceApi.SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState();
```

In this case you are setting the prototype of the object which then is "applied" to the instance when you create it using `new`

Fun fact, you can also add things to the prototype of most things, like a String or Date

Example:

```
String.prototype.logAWord = function(word){
    console.log(word);
};

// "" is an instance of String
// Logs "Hello"
"".logAWord("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks! But how does it know what instance of NavigationSetApi I want it to use?

Comment: Because there is only ever one, its simply just an object with some functions in it that you are using. "`static`" almost.

Comment: Example of the difference between an instance in a second.

Comment: Cheers for the extra information. This is exactly where I was getting confused. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a `bind` to keep the correct state of `this` and access the node via an argument:

```
SyncAllNavigationSetCssToState: function () {
    this.GetAllNavigationSets().each(function (i,node) {
        this.SyncNavigationSetCssToState($(node));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

But simply accessing the `NavigationSetApi` variable is easier (and less expensive, I believe).

Comment: He already has a reference to the object containing the method, `NavigationSetApi`

Comment: Fair point, I'll leave this here though for a view of some other approaches

Comment: It was my first thought as well :P. But `this` is just `NavigationSetApi` anyway

Comment: Yeah, you're method is the simplest so it should be the answer. I will actually edit my answer to remove the first approach since this is generally considered a hack anyway!